# ways to fill n places with fixed values

Tags: algorithm, combinations, permutation

what are the number of ways in which we can fill n places with 2 fixed values and rest places with values between the 2 selected ones such that we get no duplicates?

example : n=4 , fixed values 1 and 3

```
case 1 : fix 1 on position 1 and 3 on position 2

1 3 1 1
1 3 1 2
1 3 2 1
1 3 2 2
1 3 1 3
1 3 3 1
1 3 3 3
1 3 2 3
1 3 3 2

case 2 : fix 1 on position 1 and 3 on position 3

1 1 3 1
1 1 3 2
1 2 3 1
1 2 3 2
1 3 3 2
1 2 3 3
1 3 3 1
1 1 3 3
1 3 3 3
now in case 1 and 2 : 1 3 3 3 and 1 3 3 1 and 1 3 3 2 are repeating 

case 3 : ....similarly other cases follow
```

what i have done till now is :`nC2 * POWER( (max-min+1) , n-2 ) - duplicates` but not able to subtract duplicates.

Comment: Could please clarify how many cases are you considering and how are they defined? Is perhaps that you have to consider all the possible positioning of the 2 fixed values in any 2 positions? ..or the number of cases and positions to use are given as separate data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand but if I understand well you have n (a number of digits) and a range of numbers applicable. x is the number of numbers in this range.

You have to see this as counting for base x.

Exemple :

```
x = 3 (we really don't care about min and max it change nothing)
n = 4

1 1 1 1
1 1 1 2
1 1 1 3
1 1 2 1
1 1 2 2


etc.
```

So the number of filling should be :

```
POWER(x, n)-POWER(x, n-1)
```

When x is what you call max-min+1

For your example their is 54 different ways to fill